# Tool for turning document photos to pdf

Tags: pdf, photos, scanning, document-scanning

I want to compile photos of my notebooks (taken with phone) into a pdf.

The photos are mostly black and white, with some red and blue.

They need perspective adjustments because they are not taken straight-on.

I tried Google PhotoScan but it's really slow, and has double-vision at some places. I tried Adobe Scan but it lost my very first document (seems to be an uploading issue: if the internet breaks during upload, the file is lost?).

I think the best way is to just take photos and then batch process them on a computer. What tool can you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue that we students (somewhat lazy) face while copying notes. The best and short way to get things done is to take the pictures in a sequence and make a pdf instantly. However, there are very few apps that can do this properly.

As you mentioned, you've tried all the top apps in this category, but you missed one. Try Microsoft Lens - this is the perfect tool that allows you to click upto 20 pictures all at once, and make pdf straight away. Even if you have pictures clicked previously, you can process them to enhance their quality and make a pdf very quickly. You will get a perfectly scanned-quality picture, with modes such as 'White board', 'Documents' etc.

Hope this helps.